# What is "couldn't communicate with a helper application" error in Macox

Tags: zip, finder, icloud

I'm trying to "zip" (by using the compress option in Finder) a few files that are in my icloud directory, but it is stalling with the error in the title:

[image]

After getting this error, Finder freezes and must be restarted by force in Activity Monitor.

What's up?

fyi, I can zip just fine from the command line via `zip`